# Migration from log4j 1.x to log4j 2.12.1

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

i currently upgraded log4j 1.x to log4j 2.12.1 and when i wanted to start the program i get the following error message:

```
2020-10-15 10:44:38,092 main ERROR The parameter is null: filePattern
2020-10-15 10:44:38,094 main ERROR The parameter is null: policy
2020-10-15 10:44:38,095 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: Arguments given for element RollingFile are invalid: field 'filePattern' has invalid value 'null', field 'policy' has invalid value 'null'
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.injectFields(PluginBuilder.java:208)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:121)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1002)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:942)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:934)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:552)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:241)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:288)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:579)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:651)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:668)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:581)
        at com.AJAx.first.server.FirstServer.<clinit>(FirstServer.java:10)

2020-10-15 10:44:38,100 main ERROR The parameter is null: filePattern
2020-10-15 10:44:38,101 main ERROR The parameter is null: policy
2020-10-15 10:44:38,101 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: Arguments given for element RollingFile are invalid: field 'filePattern' has invalid value 'null', field 'policy' has invalid value 'null'
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.injectFields(PluginBuilder.java:208)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:121)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1002)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:942)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:934)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:552)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:241)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:288)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:579)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:651)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:668)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:581)
        at com.AJAx.first.server.FirstServer.<clinit>(FirstServer.java:10)

2020-10-15 10:44:38,111 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2020-10-15 10:44:38,111 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders
```

i think it has to be something with the properties File, but i am really not sure if i didnt made some mistakes with the migration:

old log4j 1.x:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, DefaultAppender, ErrorAppender, ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.DefaultAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] %c [%X{request} %X{command}] - %m%n

# DefaultAppender uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.DefaultAppender.File=../var/first-server.log
log4j.appender.DefaultAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.DefaultAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DefaultAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] %c [%X{request} %X{command}] - %m%n

# ErrorAppender uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender.File=../var/first-server_error.log
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] %c [%X{request} %X{command}] - %m%n
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender.threshold=ERROR

log4j.logger.com.ajax.db=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.ajax.util=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.first.ajax.server=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.mchange=WARN
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO
log4j.logger.com.first.ajax.common.util=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=WARN
log4j.logger.org.mortbay=WARN
```

the new log4j2:

```
status=ERROR
rootLogger.level=DEBUG
appenders=default,error,console

appender.console.type=console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.target=SYSTEM_OUT
appender.default.type=RollingFile
appender.default.name=RollingFile
appender.error.type=RollingFile
appender.error.name=RollingFile

appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] %c [%X{request} %X{command}] - %m%n

# DefaultAppender uses PatternLayout.
appender.default.fileName=../var/first-server.log
appender.default.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
appender.default.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.default.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] %c [%X{request} %X{command}] - %m%n

# ErrorAppender uses PatternLayout.
appender.error.fileName=../var/first-server_error.log
appender.error.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
appender.error.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.error.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] %c [%X{request} %X{command}] - %m%n
appender.error.filter.threshold.type=ThresholdFilter
appender.error.filter.threshold.level=error

rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT

logger.db.name=com.ajax.db
logger.db.level=DEBUG
logger.util.name=com.ajax.util
logger.util.level=DEBUG
logger.server.name=com.first.ajax.server
logger.server.level=DEBUG
logger.mchange.name=com.mchange
logger.mchange.level=WARN
logger.springframework.name=org.springframework
logger.springframework.level=INFO
logger.util.name=com.Ajax.first.common.util
logger.util.level=WARN
logger.cxf.name=org.apache.cxf
logger.cxf.level=WARN
logger.mortbay.name=org.mortbay
logger.mortbay.level=WARN
```

Can someone help there?

----EDIT---------

```
status=ERROR
rootLogger.level=%%logging_level%%
appenders= default, error, console

appender.console.type=console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.target=SYSTEM_OUT
appender.default.type=RollingFile
appender.default.name=RollingFile
appender.error.type=RollingFile
appender.error.name=RollingFile

appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] %c [%X{request} %X{command}] - %m%n

# DefaultAppender uses PatternLayout.
appender.default.fileName=../var/first-server.log
appender.default.filePattern=../var/first-server-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
appender.default.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.default.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] %c [%X{request} %X{command}] - %m%n
appender.default.policies.type = Policies
appender.default.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.default.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.default.policies.time.modulate = true

# ErrorAppender uses PatternLayout.
appender.error.fileName=../var/first-server_error.log
appender.error.filePattern=../var/first-server_error-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
appender.error.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.error.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] %c [%X{request} %X{command}] - %m%n
appender.error.filter.threshold.type=ThresholdFilter
appender.error.filter.threshold.level=ERROR
appender.error.policies.type = Policies
appender.error.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.error.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.error.policies.time.modulate = true

rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT

logger.db.name=com.ajax.db
logger.db.level=WARN
logger.util.name=com.ajax.util
logger.util.level=WARN
logger.mchange.name=com.mchange
logger.mchange.level=WARN
logger.springframework.name=org.springframework
logger.springframework.level=WARN
logger.util.name=com.ajax.first.common.util
logger.util.level=WARN
logger.cxf.name=org.apache.cxf
logger.cxf.level=WARN
logger.mortbay.name=org.mortbay
logger.mortbay.level=WARN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some configurations in your log4j2 properties. You created RollingFile appenders, however you didn't define how they should roll. That's why the errors are telling you that `filePattern` and `policy` are null. Note that the `DailyRollingFileAppender` class no longer exists in log4j2, so you have to basically set it up yourself.

The `filePattern` property tells you how to name the file when you roll it. For example, if you wanted the rolled files to contain the date, you could do something like

```
appender.default.filePattern=../var/first-server-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
```

which would give you a name like `first-server-20201017.log`.

You also need to set up the policies to describe when to roll. In your case it looks like you want daily rolling, so it would be something like

```
appender.default.policies.type = Policies
appender.default.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.default.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.default.policies.time.modulate = true
```

[This page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties) gives a lot more details about configuring log4j2.

Comment: thanks, dont get the error anymore! But now i get the logfile with nothing written in it. My new properties file is on my post

Comment: I typically use the XML configuration so I'm not as familiar with the properties file, however it looks like you don't have any `appenderRefs` set up so nothing is going to be sent from the loggers to the appenders. Also it looks like you named both of your loggers `RollingFile` so that might also be an issue.

Comment: thank you very much! It finally worked after i added the appenderRefs, you are a lifesaver :)

Comment: Glad I could help!